# WPF Mouse binding in ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I have this code , and i want to add Mouse Left click bindding .
I've done it like this , but for some reason seams that it have on effect.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" IsEnabled="{Binding UserGroupUpdatePermission}" ItemsSource="{Binding UserGroupTypeList }" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="300" Height="auto">
    <ListBox.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="{Binding Path = SaveCommand }" Gesture="LeftClick" />
    </ListBox.InputBindings>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Checked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

am i doing some thing wrong ? is there any outher way for doing it ?

Comment: please share the viewmodel as well which contains SaveCommand.

Comment: Left Click? Are you sure you're not looking for Right click? My natural guess would be that Left Click is already used to select items so commands would be overridden anyway

Comment: yes , I need to set it to dirty when one of the checkBoxes are clicked. the problem is that the checked binding is automatic and i can't added the dirty variable there

Comment: save command it's only for checking it can be any ather Constructor. i set a break point there and the program is not getting there on mouse click